# Is the order of the MongoDb update operators guaranteed with the Node.Js native driver?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Considering the following MongoDb update performed with the Node.JS driver:

```
collection.update({ /* query */}, { $unset: { 'gp': 1 }, $set: { 'gp.status': 'AB' }}, function(err) {
    // ...
})
```

Is there any guarantee that the `$unset` will be performed first and `$set` will be performed afterwards? This considering that theoretically one should not rely on the order of the keys of a javascript object. This also assumes that MongoDb itself guarantees the order of the update operators (for that I have asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24500959/454103))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No those operations are not ordered. In fact you will get some error if you try that tells you that you cannot modify items in the same statement with the same path. So you cannot [**`$unset`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) and [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) in the same update statement, as both are essentially trying to act on "gp".

What you can do if your MongoDB version is 2.6 or greater is use "bulk update" operations to do as near as possible to an atomic update and also guarantee order:

```
var bulk = collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
bulk.find({ /* query */}).updateOne({ "$unset": { "gp": 1 } });
bulk.find({ /* query */}).updateOne({ "$set": { "gp.status": "AB" } });
bulk.execute(function(err,result) {
  // Write concern result for two ops in `result`
});
```

So that is not actually one operation, but the ordered operation brings it as near as you can get with a single round trip to the server.

Answer (score 3):

You can't target the same field with multiple update operators like that, but in this case you don't need to as you can accomplish it with a single `$set` that replaces the whole `gp` field:

```
collection.update({ /* query */}, {$set: {gp: {status: 'AB'}}, function(err) {
    // ...
})
```